# How to format text in options for select in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following json object:

```
$scope.values = [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "code": "Code 1",
            "name": "Sample 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "code": "Code 2",
            "name": "Sample 2"  
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "code": "Code 3",
            "name": "Sample 3"
        }
    ];
```

In select tag, I have this:

```
<select name="c_id" ng-options="c.id as c.code for c in values"></select>
```

The generated select options is:

```
Code 1
Code 2
Code 3
```

Is there any way to format the text in the options like the following?

```
Code 1 -- Sample 1
Code 2 -- Sample 2
Code 3 -- Sample 3
```

Or I'll just have to prepare the values before attaching them to the model?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do it by using this syntax:

```
ng-options="c.id as (c.code + ' -- '+ c.name) for c in values"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/6EkL7/1/

Or someone may like next syntax:

```
ng-options="c.id as [c.code,c.name].join(' -- ') for c in values"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/6EkL7/2/

But in some cases there is rationality in using a Filter , like:

```
app.filter("formatter",function(){
    return function(item){
        return item.code+ " -- " + item.name;
    }
})
```

And: `ng-options="c.id as c|formatter for c in values"`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/K8572/

Comment: awesome way to achieve this. Grt!

Comment: @AshishKumar , yes , Angular is fantastic!

Comment: You just made me realize the 'as' clause can be a method just like the 'for' clause, such as "foo as barize(foo) for activeFoos()".  Thank you for that.  Not sure if I'll ever do such a thing, but the G.I. Joe in me is happy to know it.

Comment: That's awesome answer. Thanks buddy..!!

Comment: Last one helped me along with the link.  Thank you! +1

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can achieve that by invoke `ng-repeat` for `option`,

**HTML**

```
   <select> 
        <option ng-repeat="v in values" value="{{v.id}}">
          {{v.code}} -- {{v.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

**JS**

*the same*

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/59/)**</kbd>