# How do I format an angular drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I want to change the format of an angular drop down. The drop down serves to filter a list of Matches based on ng-model and the customerFilter function. Here is what I currently have:

HTML

```
<div class="drop-toggle w-dropdown-toggle">
 <select  ng-model="filterVariable" ng-change= "customFilter(filterVariable, allMatches)" ng-options="XXX for XXX in categories">
  <option value="">By Categories</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I'd like to bring the functionality of this filter to the following format with all of its CSS but I can't figure out how to get ng-model, ng-change and ng-options wired up to it.

```
  <div class="sort-drop w-dropdown" data-delay="0">
   <div class="drop-toggle w-dropdown-toggle">
     <div class="sort-label">By Category</div>
     <div class="sort-icon w-icon-dropdown-toggle"></div>
   </div>
   <nav class="category-dropdown w-dropdown-list">
     <a class="category-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
     <a class="category-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
     <a class="category-link w-dropdown-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
   </nav>
 </div>


<div class="flex-offer-content-div" ng-repeat="match in Matches">
  <div class="re-image-div w-clearfix">
    <img class="rebate-image" src="{{match.offerDisplay}}" width="160">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.categories = ["Men", "Women", "Children"];

$scope.Matches = [{id: 1, offerDisplay: "Men"}, {id: 2, offerDisplay: "Women"}, {id: 3, offerDisplay: "Women"}];

$scope.filterVariable = ""

$scope.customFilter = function (cat, allMatches) {
   if(cat === null){
      $scope.Matches = allMatches;
   } else {
      $scope.Matches = _.compact(_.map(allMatches, function(n){
         if(n.offerDisplay == cat)){
            return n;
         } else {
            return;
         }
       }))  
       return $scope.Matches;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be specific when you say "format".

hope this helps you
 [How to format text in options for select in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967045/how-to-format-text-in-options-for-select-in-angularjs)